# Spoofing IP address WITHOUT any external module via Python

Tags: python-2.7, ip, ip-address, spoofing

I want to ask, how to spoof an IP address, but without any external modules? Until now I've been using Scapy module, but I want to make it on my own, see how it is done and maybe learn something new. Here is the code with Scapy module:

```
from scapy.all import *

SPOOFED_PACKET = IP(src=SRC_IP, dst=DST_IP) / TCP(sport=SRC_PORT, dport=DST_PORT) / PAYLOAD
send(SPOOFED_PACKET)
```

Comment: You can build the packet from scratch, filling byte array with correct bytes in the correct order. Then send it to raw socket.

Comment: See this: https://gist.github.com/cslarsen/11339448

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"""Demonstrates how to construct and send raw Ethernet packets on the
network.
You probably need root privs to be able to bind to the network interface,
e.g.:
    $ sudo python sendeth.py
"""

from socket import *

def sendeth(src, dst, eth_type, payload, interface = "eth0"):
  """Send raw Ethernet packet on interface."""

  assert(len(src) == len(dst) == 6) # 48-bit ethernet addresses
  assert(len(eth_type) == 2) # 16-bit ethernet type

  s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)

  # From the docs: "For raw packet
  # sockets the address is a tuple (ifname, proto [,pkttype [,hatype]])"
  s.bind((interface, 0))
  return s.send(src + dst + eth_type + payload)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  print("Sent %d-byte Ethernet packet on eth0" %
    sendeth("\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xBE\xEF",
            "\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xBE\xEF",
            "\x7A\x05",
            "hello"))
```

To include an IPv4 header:

```
"""Demonstrates how to construct and send raw Ethernet packets on the
network.

You probably need root privs to be able to bind to the network interface,
e.g.:

    $ sudo python sendeth.py
"""

from socket import *

def sendeth(ethernet_packet, payload, interface = "eth0"):
  """Send raw Ethernet packet on interface."""
  s = socket(AF_PACKET, SOCK_RAW)

  # From the docs: "For raw packet
  # sockets the address is a tuple (ifname, proto [,pkttype [,hatype]])"
  s.bind((interface, 0))
  return s.send(ethernet_packet + payload)

def pack(byte_sequence):
  """Convert list of bytes to byte string."""
  return b"".join(map(chr, byte_sequence))

if __name__ == "__main__":
      # Note that this example contains HARDCODED packets, meaning that
      # it will ONLY work on the system it was designed for.

      # I got these values by sending a ping while running Wireshark.
      # You can do so yourself.  Another way to construct these manually is to use
      # the impacket library (sudo pip install impacket)

      # src=fe:ed:fa:ce:be:ef, dst=52:54:00:12:35:02, type=0x0800 (IP)
      ethernet_packet = [0x52, 0x54, 0x00, 0x12, 0x35, 0x02, 0xfe, 0xed, 0xfa,
                         0xce, 0xbe, 0xef, 0x08, 0x00]

      # src=10.0.2.15, dst=195.88.54.16 (vg.no), checksum, etc.
      ipv4_header = [0x45, 0x00, 0x00, 0x54, 0x05, 0x9f, 0x40, 0x00, 0x40, 0x01,
                     0x2f, 0x93, 0x0a, 0x00, 0x02, 0x0f, 0xc3, 0x58, 0x36, 0x10]

      # echo (ping) request, checksum 2b45, etc
      icmp_ping = [0x08, 0x00, 0x2b, 0x45, 0x11, 0x22, 0x00, 0x02, 0xa9, 0xf4, 0x5c,
                   0x53, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xf5, 0x7b, 0x01, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
                   0x00, 0x00, 0x10, 0x11, 0x12, 0x13, 0x14, 0x15, 0x16, 0x17, 0x18,
                   0x19, 0x1a, 0x1b, 0x1c, 0x1d, 0x1e, 0x1f, 0x20, 0x21, 0x22, 0x23,
                   0x24, 0x25, 0x26, 0x27, 0x28, 0x29, 0x2a, 0x2b, 0x2c, 0x2d, 0x2e,
                   0x2f, 0x30, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37]

      payload = "".join(map(chr, ipv4_header + icmp_ping))

      # Construct Ethernet packet with an IPv4 ICMP PING request as payload
      r = sendeth(pack(ethernet_packet),
                  pack(ipv4_header + icmp_ping))
      print("Sent Ethernet w/IPv4 ICMP PING payload of length %d bytes" % r)
```

Comment: I have three question about this code. (1) What should I push into the variable `eth_type`? (2) What is this `print("Sent %d-byte Ethernet packet on eth0" %
    sendeth("\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xBE\xEF",
            "\xFE\xED\xFA\xCE\xBE\xEF",
            "\x7A\x05",
            "hello"))`? (3) Should variables `src` & `dst` be tuples containing `(IP, PORT)`?

Comment: `eth_type` should be the rax hex that corresponds with the proper EtherType (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EtherType). The `print` statement sends and prints the ethernet frame at the same time. And `src` and `dst` are MAC address since this is the Ethernet layer, not the IP layer

Comment: Thanks for that `eth_type`, but I just realised, that I until now kind of misunderstood the `Ethernet frame`, so now I know, that I was looking for changing the `SRC_IP` & `DST_IP` in the `Payload`. Can you tell me, how that can be done? Thanks for answer

Comment: I've added an IP example. You'll need to add an IP header plus whatever else you're looking for.